# Could not find an NgModule in angular-cli when adding a component

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a component using using the angular/cli & get the following error:

> Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
>   Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule

Comment: Please try this approach [stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045) Should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of new SPA templates. I had the same problem and solved it by installing "Angular files" extension for VS Code. It generates needed files from the context menu. Then you just need to add Component in app.module.shared.ts