# Angular2 - Could not find an NgModule

Tags: angular, macos, terminal, angular-cli

Hello I've just created a new project from the CLI using the simple

```
ng new frontend
```

command however once I go into my project to:

```
cd frontend/src/app
```

and try to generate a new component like so

```
ng generate component about
```

I get the following error message in my terminal(MacOS): 
Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.

I have installed Angular 2 globally and when I run my

```
ng --version
```

I receive the following:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.0
@schematics/angular          0.6.0
@schematics/update           0.6.0
rxjs                         6.1.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

inside of my `Angular.json` I have:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend"
}
```

And digging even further: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

**What I've tried:**
I have tried reinstalling Angular. I have confirmed my TypeScript is up to date. my NPM is up to date and so on. I've created a new project following the most basic steps of the tutorial provided at `Angular.io` to no avail.

If anyone can lecture me on what is going wrong here I'd greatly appreciate it.

---

While drafting this post I had the brilliant idea of running this process through my IDE's terminal and shockingly `ng generate component about` worked without a problem. However being curious and wanting to know what is wrong with my native terminal I figured I'd post after all.

---

**EDIT 2:**
So random thought popped in my head plain and simple File Permissions...yup
using `sudo ng g c about` worked. So there you have it I suppose. Hopefully this was helpful to someone out there.

Comment: Have you tried running the command from the `frontend/` directory?  Instead of the src directory.

Comment: @m.e.conroy yes and I receive the same message `Could not find an NgModule`

Comment: Not sure what the difference between your IDE terminal and MAC terminal would be.  The only thing I can think of is that your MAC terminal didn't know where to find Node or NPM, but somehow your IDE terminal's environment was set correctly.

Comment: @m.e.conroy me neither, especially confused since it worked about a week ago. Would it be valuable to list what my IDE is? Anyway to verify whatever my Mac terminal has problems finding Node or NPM?

Comment: Just generate the component in the root of your angular app.

Comment: When i run ng --version in a terminal  i get the angular version and the modules in the entry Angular.
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Have you installed the angular cli global and locally ?

Answer (score 6):

you should run this command 'ng g c component-name' inside is app folder.

**1) cd src/app**
**2) ng g c component name**

Comment: That was the answer in my case, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was in angular.json file. I had to remove all the 'projectname-e2e' project at the angular.json file for fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular@7 `ng g c` works from the root app folder. No need to change anything - just run from the base directory something like

`ng g c features/shopping-list/components/shopping-list-edit
=>
CREATE src/app/features/shopping-list/components/shopping-list-edit/shopping-list-edit.component.ts (316 bytes)`

Answer (score 1):

Could not find ngModule can be solved by passing `--module=<path to app.module.ts>`

There are multiple ways to fix this issue one among them is as follows,

```
ng g c components/list-template --module=modules/app.module.ts
```

For other options with respect to generate component is here https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Answer (score 0):

Change `root` to the directory where your module is in `angular.json`

From:

```
root:""
```

to directory of app module:

```
root: "/src/app"
```

Answer (score -1):

The code for generating a `component` and resolving closest `NgModule` is quite straightforward. You can find it here https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts [**Note:** link currently dead 15 June 2020]

It doesn't depend on the typescript, npm etc. version. Only on the @angular/cli version (and indirectly on the devkit) which in your case is the latest. All should be working fine; at least it does on my end.

Comment: Your link is dead.