# Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule

Tags: angular, nrwl

I get the error in the subject of this post when I use the CLI to create a new component: `ng g c my-component --project=my-project`  (No component is created)

I've seen other posts with the same error message, but none of them also include Nrwl/Nx, which I believe is somehow involved.  Project started as Ng4 and was upgraded to Ng6.

**Environment:**

- Angular CLI: 6.0.8
- Node: 8.9.4
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 6.0.6
- @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
- @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
- @angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
- @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
- @angular/cdk                      6.3.1
- @angular/cli                      6.0.8
- @angular/material                 6.3.1
- @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
- @schematics/angular               0.6.1
- @schematics/update                0.6.8
- rxjs                              6.2.1
- typescript                        2.7.2
- webpack                           4.8.3
- nrwl/nx 6.1.0

**UPDATE #1**

I tried dropping the `--project` flag entirely ( so just `ng g c my-component`) and still get the same problem.  Not sure what that means, yet.

Comment: Please try this approach [stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045) Should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up totally deleting `node_modules`, clearing out the yarn cache and then running `yarn` to reinstall all packages.  I also edited my `angular.json` file so that my pathing looked like this for all applications and libraries:

```
"root": "libs/my-lib",
"sourceRoot": "libs/my-lib/src"
```

I'm not sure which of those fixed the problem, but all appears to be OK now. At least the immediate problem went away.

Answer (score 166):

## **Quick fix**

1) **Change** current **directory** in cmd/terminal to **src/app**

`cd src/app` (linux)

`cd .\src\app\` (windows)

2) **Run** commands now

`ng g c myComponent`

Comment: The reason why this works, is that your project's default src/app folder hierarchy has been changed. Therefore, anything else that doesn't fit this situation will not work. When you generate a default project with cli, you shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: That is not the only reason, if you run the `ng generate component` in a folder different to `src/app` you will get that error.

Answer (score 39):

The generate of components aims to do 2 things:

- create **source code** for the component
- registers the component in a **module** (by default, in the `app.module.ts`)

The problem is, that you don't have an `app.module.ts`. You renamed it to something else, or perhaps even have multiple of them. In that case there are 2 possible solutions:

1. you do the registration of the component manually. **(easiest)**

   ng g component mycomponent **--skip-import**
2. you specify the module with the `-m` switch. **(might be broken)** There is a long thread about it here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/526

Comment: Or you moved app.module.ts to another folder such as modules folder

Comment: or you are not in src/app folder so app.modules.ts is not available in the current. see the reply from @Debojyoti

Answer (score 23):

Run component generation command(ng g c component-name) from where the app.module.ts file is located.

Answer (score 16):

You are not inside app folder...
cd app on windows, and then run command

Answer (score 9):

### Working 100%

Try `--skip-import`

```
ng g c mycomponent --skip-import
```

### or change directory src/app ;

open the terminal on click on app -> enter comand `ng g c 'your component name'` and hit enter

I think These are the error you getting click once and check it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSG7c.png

Answer (score 8):

Your current directory in cmd window matters.
Run this command from the '**src/app**' folder in the project. 
It should work.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the line `"cli": { "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics" }` from angular.json file and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You may have changed the file **app.module.ts** to other folder (out of folder **app**). Ionic is not finding the file.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the location for .module.ts file. I was running this command from /src folder, while app module was inside /src/app folder.

When run the same command from /src/app  path. It is working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, In angular.json file, I searched for my-project-e2e (replace my-project with your project name)
and then I changed:

`"root": ""` to `"root": "e2e"`
and saved it. Everything was working again.

The solution was specified in this [link](http://www.fwait.com/angular-6-cli-component-service-generate-issue/).

Answer (score 2):

1. **First way**:
   I think first you have to go to inside your app folder then type cmd;
   `ng g c your_com_name --spec false`
   or `ng g c your_com_name`
   It will definitely create your component or solve your problem.
2. **second way**:
   Remove your e2e from your `angular.json->projects`:
   definitely

   ```js
   { 
       your_project_name-e2e:{}
   }
   ```

   example: `my-first-app-e2e`

   ```js
   {
         "root": "e2e/",
         "projectType": "application",
         "architect": {
           "e2e": {
             "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
             "options": {
               "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
               "devServerTarget": "my-first-app:serve"
             }
           },
           "lint": {
             "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
             "options": {
               "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
               "exclude": [
                 "**/node_modules/**"
               ]
             }
           }
         }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty weird answer, but the problem occur because I have open my project in the src directory only. Reopening the entire project folder resolves the issue.

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer to this issue. The users should be in the root folder while performing Angular CLI commands.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in the right path (I mean in the path you are working in)
so just verify this in the console by print working directory (pwd) and change it. This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Enter ** cd .\app\ ** in the terminal or type "**cd app + Tab**". Once you are in the app folder, the ng command works!

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me and in my case it was due to me generating a new component outside of the app folder, I bought the new component inside the app folder and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully helps someone, I had 2 issues:

1. I had 2 modules on the same folder level as `app.module.ts` that referenced `NgModule`, I moved it to a separate folder
2. My `components` folder was outside of the `app` folder, you have to be cded into app in order to run the command for it to find `NgModule`

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Turned out to be somehow related to the name of the root component. Renaming back to 'app' resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem (in ionic 4) was that the file app-routing.module.ts was missing. I had to create an empty one, before adding new pages worked:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

From visual studio code I made a:
right click on the app folder -> click on "open in integrated terminal -> run the cmd: ng g component user.
4 files have been created. It works successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I created empty folder my own and move my old module into it. After when I tried to create component inside the folder I got same error. I deleted the empty folder and create module folder. After that I was able to create new components etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error because I was in the wrong file location.
For some reason I thought I had to do it from the file location src instead of the location above (where angular.json is and ofcourse src/ itself)

Doing the  command from root location solved it (in my case cd ..).

Answer (score 0):

you have to move to the src/app folder

simple use $cd app command to go inside

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with angular 16.2.8. Here is my package.json showing my angular version dependencies:
[image]

In this example answer I have not converted my angular application to use standalone components yet. If you use --skip-import then imports will not be added to your app.module.ts which will lead to your application having problems. In order to make sure imports are added to app.module.ts, when creating a component I had to cd to my directory where my app.module.ts was located. In my case that was the folder:

> (base-folder)/src/app
> [image]

After being in my folder where my app.module.ts was located I typed the command

```
ng g c NewComponentName -m app
```

If you have changed your app.module.ts to a new name then replace app in the command above with that name.

For a real example in my example below I created a component called PrivacyPolicy
[image]

You can see my app.module.ts added the imports successfully from the blue UPDATE text.

Here is what the import looks like in my app.module.ts after adding the component. Notice I moved my component to a components folder manually after creating my component which is why my path starts with components:
[image]