# Angular CLI create component throw error; Could not find an NgModule

Tags: node.js, angular6

I am working on Angular 6 application and trying to use CLI to create new component using 'ng g c myComponent' but getting error

My all components are under module folder of app / (root level component)

### error

```
Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.
```

### warning message

```
 Your global Angular CLI version (7.2.2) is greater than your local
 version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

 To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch 
 false".
 Two or more projects are using identical roots. Unable to determine 
 project using current working directory. Using default workspace project 
 instead.
```

when I run ng --version, I get following app versions

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.9
@angular/cli                      6.2.9
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.8.9
@schematics/update                0.8.9
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.5.3
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200919/could-not-find-an-ngmodule-use-the-skip-import-option-to-skip-importing-in-ngmo)

Comment: I suppose you may just run this command in wrong path. Are you completely sure, that you're running this command in the folder where components suppose to be?

Comment: i refer this blog but i not reaching to any solution

Comment: i believe i am in correct folder C:\Developments\Dev\MyAngularProject\src\app\modules> ng g c MyComponent

Comment: Gonzalo Lorieto, I did not got solution...

Comment: Call `ng g c MyComponent` from the same directory where the package.json is located.

Comment: I call ng g c MyComponent from the same directory where the package.json is located same error ....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app module is in the folder where you are generating the component. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I was creating a component within a specific feature (or project). And I realized I had to get into the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd:

```
ng g c <name> --skip-import
```

Add the `--skip-import` option.
Reason: It will skip new component entry in the module.